# How can Drupal users receive emails from outside Drupal?

Tags: email, drupal

I have a basic Drupal install and a bunch of users.

How could my Drupal users receive e-mails from the outside world at their address (e.g. user@my-drupal-install.com)?

Thank you!

Comment: Do your users *have* an "user@my-drupal-install.com" emailadress?

Comment: You want to do email forwarding based on the username of the user? So that email's sent to `SomeUser@my-drupal-install.com` is forwarded to SomeUser's registered email address?

Comment: Yes Greg, exactly.
It seems to be a mailserver question more than a drupal one, as indeed I can get the registered email addresses from Drupal's users table.
Any advice on how to set this up?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks all!

You've put me in the right direction and I ended up writing a script that reads the Drupal's users table and configures the mail server accordingly.
I've turned it into a small Python library for WebFaction, available at http://code.google.com/p/drupal2mail.

Hope it's useful for some!

Answer (score 2):

Drupal is a system for serving web pages, it does not run mail servers. If there is no mail server present on your system, you will need to install one. Once you have a mail server running, you can install a Drupal module such as [Webmail Plus](http://drupal.org/project/webmail_plus) to provide a webmail interface for your users.

Comment: Thank you for your comments.
I can install a mail server on the machine that's hosting drupal, no problem.  I would like to forward the mail to the email address my drupal users have registered with though, not allow them to use drupal as a webmail client.
Thank you.

Comment: In order to do that, I think you would need a Drupal module that adds a forward rule to the mail server config when a user registers or changes his e-mail address. The Drupal-site of that module would not be really hard to write (see hook_user in the api documentation) but I'm not sure which mail server would be easiest to configure from a php script.

Answer (score 1):

For the case you describe I think the best way to handle this is to set up a mail server with automatic forwarding, and run a batch process once a day or so that extracts the usernames and their e-mail addresses from your Drupal database's `user` table.  Drupal itself doesn't need to be involved in the actual sending and receiving of e-mail at all.

If you are using the Drupal username as the first part of the e-mail address then your export script could just run a query like

```
SELECT name, mail
FROM  `users` 
WHERE 1
```

as part of a shell script that populates a table of e-mail addresses to forward to.  For the correct formatting and configuration of such a file you'll really need to dig into the documentation of your e-mail server.

Comment: You could also write a Drupal module that updates the mail server whenever a user is created or their email address is changed.